# AndEngine import GLES2 project not running

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to update my project to run with AndEngine GLES2, but I have some problems. I find an article which shows what to change, but it's still not working. Here is exactly what I'm doing :

***onCreateEngineOptions()***

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add Logo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    CAMERA_WIDTH = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);


    final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(false);
    return engineOptions;
}
```

***onCreateResources()***

```
public void onCreateResources() {

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(4096, 4096, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    this.mFont = new Font(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL), 25, true, Color.BLACK);

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
    this.mEngine.getFontManager().loadFont(this.mFont);


    this.firstSprite =  BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "1.png", 0, 113); // 113x100
           // 36 other sprites, that's why I'm creating BitmapTextureAtlas with these size

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
}
```

***onCreateScene()***

```
@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    this.mScene = new Scene();
    this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(4, 4, 4));
    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

    this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);

    CAMERA_WIDTH = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    final IAreaShape ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
    final IAreaShape roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2);
    final IAreaShape left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final IAreaShape right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.KinematicBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.KinematicBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.KinematicBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.KinematicBody, wallFixtureDef);

    this.mScene.attachChild(ground);
    this.mScene.attachChild(roof);
    this.mScene.attachChild(left);
    this.mScene.attachChild(right);

    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
    this.mScene.setOnAreaTouchListener(this);

    final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 1);

    //Sprite 1
    Sprite face = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, 50, this.firstSprite);
    face.setUserData("petrol");
    Body body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
    this.mScene.registerTouchArea(face);
    this.mScene.attachChild(face);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
            // 36 sprites....
return this.mScene;
    }
```

And the problem is that when I start this activity it's not showing non of the sprites and the screen remains black even if I change it to white color.

So any ideas where is my mistake and what I'm doing wrong. (Before moving to AndEngine GLES2 everything was working except on Android Honeycomb and now I'm testing this project on HTC EVO 3d which is running with Android 2.3.4).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is your issue - I had similar problems before I added this

```
    @Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception { //
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```